# Can Successive Over-Relaxation be used for Nonlinear Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

My question was whether or not successive over-relaxation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) could be used to find solutions to a nonlinear equation. In particular I am interested if it is possible to obtain multiple solutions (assuming your nonlinear ode has multiple solutions) by varying your choice of values for the first iteration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  If your problem has been reduced to a system of non-linear algebraic equations, then, generally, that must be solved iteratively.  There are many methods -- but the first step is to find local solutions by linearizing the system.  The SOR can be used to solve the linear system.

If the solution is not unique - then which solution is obtained (if any) depends more on the initial guess - and probably not the relaxation parameter which may control rate of convergence.

For a simple analogy consider how Newton's method is used to find the roots of a single non-linear equation.

Comment: If you linearize the system then you should only expect 1 solution, correct?

Comment: The linearized system will have a unique solution - as any linear system -- if the matrix is non-singular -- and it will depend on your starting guess.  In the Newton-Raphson method which generalizes Newton to multiple dimensions, this matrix is the Jacobian of the non-linear system.  I have to recall what happens if this is non-singular. Also there are methods like conjugate gradient you may want to read up about - they can converge much faster.

Comment: If I just naively apply the relaxation iteration method to a nonlinear equation am I making an assumption that the equation is linear?